# Unable to create a managed package which has a component with lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader interface

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps

Getting the following error -

> You can only create Lightning Component Quick Actions for Component
>   Bundles containing a component that implements
>   force:lightningQuickAction and has no required attributes without a
>   default value

I have tried with both **force:lightningQuickAction** and **force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader** interfaces but it's same error always.

My bundle version is 45.0

Comment: Are there required attributes without a default value?

Comment: No. There are no required fields.

Answer (score 0):

Feels like a bug. Downgrading to 42 fixed it for me.

*didn't test other versions.

Comment: I need some features from the latest version 45.0 so can't downgrade.